# Firebase User returning no photoUrl, despite the user having a photo

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've implemented Firebase Auth for my Swift project. However, the `photoUrl` seems to be returning no photo, despite the user having a photo.

This is how I'm retrieving the `photoUrl`:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.photoUrl
```

All other fields are returning correctly, like their email, user id, display name, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  It's just not guaranteed for the user to have a photo in the system.  If you need one, you should modify your app to prompt the user to upload one and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented Firebase Authentication with a provider, then most likely you not should search the `photoUrl` directly inside the [currentuser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#currentuser) object but inside the [providerdata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#providerdata). The latter returns an array of [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html) objects. So you have to iterate to find the user that corresponds to the selected type of authentication and use the [UserInfo#photourl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html#photourl) in your code. If the image exists then this `photourl` property will certainly contain a value. Also, see that this variable has the `u` character lowercase and not uppercase.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't look like `photoUrl` has a returned value in providerdata either, so not really sure what's going on.